# Replace characters in string in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string

I have a string as "12:66 PM".Now i want to replace string 66 with 60.So i want to check if that after ":" two characters should be replaced with 60 or any value.

please suggest

Comment: Are you just replacing characters after `:`, or are you trying to change a date / time value? If it's the latter, there are better ways to handle this

Comment: This is a basic string processing question. SO is not a place to get others to write your code for you. Make an attempt at your own solution to the problem and we'll help you get it working.

Comment: Or, as Ashley rightly points out, it might be a date and time processing problem. You should probably step back and describe what you're trying to do in more general terms, and your current approach. If you're trying to manipulate dates and times there are indeed better ways to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use regexp-search-and-replace:

```
string.replacingOccurrences(of: "regexp", with: "replacement", options: .regularExpression)
```

So, in your case:

```
var time = "12:66 PM"
time.replacingOccurrences(of: ":\\d\\d", with: ":60", options: .regularExpression)
// > "12:60 PM"
```

Abstracting this into a function is straight-forward:

```
func replaceMinutes(in time: String, with minutes: String) -> String {
    return time.replacingOccurrences(of: ":\\d\\d", 
                                     with: ":\(minutes)", 
                                     options: .regularExpression)
}
```

If necessary, you may want to check that the input strings match what you expect:

```
    nil != time.range(of: "^\\d\\d:\\d\\d [AP]M$", options: .regularExpression)
&&  nil != minutes.range(of: "^\\d\\d$", options: .regularExpression)
```

If you have trouble understanding how any of this works, I recommend you read up on a) [basics of the Swift language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) and b) [regular expressions](https://regexone.com/).

Answer (score -5):

Here Is  the Logic how can you do that 
first of all you have o take last index of your input var

in Java we can do like this

String l_name = input .substring(input .lastIndexOf(":"));

And after That you can replace  l_name with your new output with variable
i hope it will help..